# What does "food satisfies a random group member" mean?

Tags: plateup

On the Witch's Hut event map, the trick card for Foggy Food says:

> Food satisfies a random group member

What does that description mean? What does Foggy Food actually do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you serve food, it will satisfy the orders at random.

For example, take a table with the orders Burger + Corn and Pizza + Fries. You can serve a plate of Burger + Corn, but it appears on the table as Corn and Fries.

You can end up serving four plated mains to two people, as happens in the video below. But with some forward planning this shouldn't be an issue.